# Get header image to overflow anything else

Tags: css

I need to force header image to overflow anything else in the webpage.

I have tried `z-index` and `overflow`: `visible`/`hidden` on about all rules, I can think of, to get the header to always overflow the page contents.

[Here](http://www.nucleargoogle.com/barkley/) is a live example of the problem, I'm asking about.

Comment: It seems to work to me. Your sticky header is always on top when displayed on scroll. What part are you talking about?

Comment: The answer below took care of it. I just can't mark his as a correct answer for another 2 minutes. TY for looking into it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're referring to the slider overlapping the logo. If yes, simply add this CSS at the bottom of your stylesheet and that would solve your problem:

```
img.normal_logo {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Yep that did it. I was trying positioning too without luck. I must have not had the correct rule with the correct combination. TYVM! it did fix it and I will vote you answered me in a couple minutes when it allows me to.